# Calculate the angle of $\theta$ in pythagoreans theorem with different units for the Adjacent and Opposite sides

Tags: triangles, computer-science, angle

[image]

In the above image I know the value of the adjacent side.  It's $298$.  I know the value of the opposite side it's $806.8$.  The problem is $298$ is in units of 'bars' on a stock chart and the value of $806.8$ is representing the price difference.  We can't mix different units and get a meaningful answer with the standard Pythagorean theorem.  **My goal is to calculate what the angle $\theta$ is in the image above.**

For example on the site tradingview.com, I drew this image.

[image]

Notice it says the angle is $-15$ degrees.  It's able to calculate that because it can assume it's a right triangle (you can kind of see it with the dashed lines acting as the other side of the right triangle).  The $-806.8$ is representing degree's of difference downwards; So that would be the **opposite side** in my diagram.  The $298$ bars would be the **adjacent side**.

This is exactly what I'm trying to do.  I uploaded the image I used above and just inversed it to further clarify.  The words are just messed up.  This matches the same orientation as the tradingview line image.

[image]

What would be the best way to go about solving this problem?

**Acceptable Answers:**

I am writing a computer program to help solve this, therefore any solution that requires multiple 'testing' is OK.  I can just run a loop to try different values until we get something that works.

Converting the price and time into some combined unit is OK, all we ultimately care about is the angle

I could program something where the user plugs in different values until the angle 'looks' like a $45$ degree angle to get the ratios right.

So this should give a lot of creative possibilities to discover an answer and I'm not sure the best route to go.  I have looked around and found no solutions for this kind of problem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I removed the [tag:pythagorean-triples] tag, because the lengths are not all integers

Comment: That's fine, I wasn't sure what to use for this.  Any tag suggestions?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but if the units on the sides are different, then the angle depends on the scales of each side. If that's not the case, and you have the length of each side, then you can just use trig.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean with scale of each side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no natural metric (no sense of length or angle) on a graph with different units. You can stretch the graph horizontally or vertically and change the apparent angle.

So just pick any numbers $a,b>0$ (with appropriate units) and say that the hypotenuse is

$$\sqrt{a*(\text{adjacent})^2+b*(\text{opposite})^2}$$

and the angle is

$$\arccos\frac{\sqrt a*(\text{adjacent})}{\sqrt{a*(\text{adjacent})^2+b*(\text{opposite})^2}}=\arctan\frac{\sqrt b*(\text{opposite})}{\sqrt a *(\text{adjacent})}.$$

See [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) and [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor).

Comment: Can you give me an example with the number I gave? I'm curious how that would look plugged into your equation.  I should mention that it's not possible to have the adjacent and opposite be the same units, so not sure what you meant by appropriate units.  Any help is appreciated, trying for now to go through the equations to see if it creates a similar angle result.

Comment: You could take $$a=\frac{1}{(298\text{ bar})^2},\quad b=\frac{1}{(\$806.8)^2}$$ to make the angle exactly $45^\circ$ (I'm assuming it's between $0$ and $90^\circ$).

Comment: Just treat the units as algebraic variables, and try to make them cancel out. Regardless of the numerical value, $a$ should have units of $1/(\text{bar})^2$ and $b$ should have units of $1/\$^2$.

Comment: How does the a and b example you give translate into 45∘ (degrees)? Guess I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it for some reason.

Comment: You're given that $$\text{adjacent}=298\text{ bar},\quad\text{opposite}=\$806.8$$ So if $a=1/(\text{adjacent})^2$ and $b=1/(\text{opposite})^2$, then we get $\arctan\frac11=45^\circ$.

Comment: (The values of $a$ and $b$ are supposed to be fixed, and to apply to all right triangles, not just this one.)

Comment: In my example on trading view the angle came out to 15 degrees.  Is it possible this will get to an answer close to that or is what you are saying that is impossible? Like for example, maybe tradingview was using pixels behind the scenes so that is how they got that angle? Sorry in advance if I'm asking dumb questions.

Comment: If you have a graph with a specific shape (that you can't stretch), then you probably need the conversion factors between $\text{bar},\$ $ and pixels (or whatever the graph's length units are).

Comment: (Notice that the comments don't update immediately after editing, so we may miss something the other said.)

Comment: So I guess I misunderstood your question. You don't want an arbitrary metric; you want to figure out the metric that's being used.

Comment: If you're given the angle $\theta$, then you can figure out the ratio of the coefficients: $$\sqrt{\frac ba}=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{opposite}}*\tan\theta;$$ and that's all you need to find the angles of other right triangles.

Comment: So because I know the angle on the chart at that moment I can figure out the coefficients, interesting.  I will give this a try.  The reality is that I don't know the angle of theta because what I showed was an arbitrary example that will be different everytime, but I believe the chart will be the same everytime, in terms of how stretched it is and so forth, or I can ensure that it will be so the calculations work.

Comment: So the new equation you gave me, how would I use this? Can you give me an example of how that for example could translate into figuring out other triangles?

Comment: So I tested changing the zoom level on the map on the line I drew on tradingview and it did indeed start changing! This means the angle is relative to the current view you have! Very interesting... So the angle is very dependent upon how you are viewing it.

Comment: You have one triangle with $\theta$ and $\text{adj., opp.}$. Plug these into my commented equation to get the ratio $\sqrt b/\sqrt a$. Then put this ratio into the equation in the answer above, to find the angle $\theta'$ of any other right triangle with lengths $\text{adj.', opp.'}$: $$\theta'=\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt b}{\sqrt a}\frac{\text{opp.'}}{\text{adj.'}}\right)$$